# Convert hex to big integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, integer, hex

Trying to convert hex to big integer with TSQL:

According to online calculator [here](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php) (hex to decimal),

> 800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D

must give a result:

> 63680997318088143281752740767766707563546963464218564507450892460763521488675430192536461

In SQL I trying:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D', 2))
```

which gave me

> -4735785797357674083

Does anyone know how I would do this in TSQL?

Comment: This is sooooo way out of range of BIGINT

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql) for the limits of BIGINT.

Comment: ok, i know about limits of BIGINT . i mean just big numeric value

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft, `bigint` type does not offer enough precision to support values of such magnitude:

```
Data type   Range               Storage
---------   ---------------     -------
bigint      -2^63 to 2^63-1     8 Bytes
```

This means that the highest number that you can successfully convert from `VARBINARY` to `BIGINT` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

TSQL lacks numeric types that could represent unbounded integer numbers. You should read `VARBINARY` as a sequence of bytes into your program, and use the facilities of the "host language" (C, C++, C#, Java, etc.) to convert that sequence of bytes into a large number.